# Making arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management() work on CURRENT project of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, layers, symbology, arcgis-pro

I cannot make the `ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management` work on ArcGIS Pro by any means. The following code runs smoothly but does not give any results:

```
import arcpy
    
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.activeMap
layer = aprxMap.listLayers()[0]
symblayer = r"C:\referencelayer.lyrx"
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layers, symblayer)
aprx.save()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To test this in ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0 I used a project with one map and one polygon layer in it.

1. I opened the project and gave the layer a very bright color, which was easy to distinguish from its original, and used Share | Layer File to save C:\Temp\referencelayer.lyrx (I did not have permissions to save it as C:\referencelayer.lyrx)
2. I closed the project without saving.
3. I restarted ArcGIS Pro with the same project and saw that the layer had its original colour
4. I opened the Python window and typed in these commands in this order.

---

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.activeMap
layer = aprxMap.listLayers()[0]
symblayer = r"C:\Temp\referencelayer.lyrx"
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, symblayer)
```

5. At this point the layer colour changed to be the very bright one obtained from the layer file.
6. I then saved the project using ArcPy

---

```
aprx.save()
```

7. I closed ArcGIS Pro and then re-opened the project.
8. As expected the layer had the very bright colour.

I think the [comment from @KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337706/how-to-make-applysymbologyfromlayer-management-work-on-current-on-arcgis-pro#comment550956_337706) was probably correct in that the main difference between my code and yours is the attention I paid to using a variable named `layer` in two places rather than setting `layer` and then trying to retrieve a value from `layers`.